# First time working with classes in Javascript, I was wondering how to add a setInterval to this code so I could move the square(player1) smoothly

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to be able to move the square when hitting the left arrow button for instance. Although the code somewhat works below, I would like to be able to add a set interval to the show() function in the player class so that it would also clearRect as well as make my square move more smoothly. Here is my code: Thank you in advance...

```
<body>
    <canvas width="400" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
    var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c=a.getContext("2d");
    
    class player{
        constructor(){
            this.x=200;
            this.y=200;
        }
        
        show(){
            c.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
            c.fillStyle="black";
            c.beginPath();
            c.rect(this.x,this.y,30,30);
            c.fill();
            c.closePath();
        }
        
        moveUp(){
            this.y-=2;
        }
        moveDown(){
            this.y+=2;
        }
        moveLeft(){
            this.x-=2;
            
        }
        moveRight(){
            this.x+=2
        }
    }
    
    var player1=new player();
    
    window.onkeydown=function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==37){
            player1.show();
            player1.moveLeft();
        }
    }
    
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: So instead of changing the player's x by two in one go, you want it to do it in smaller increments? e.g. change x by 0.2 ten times, in order to give it a smoother effect. This could be done with `setInterval`, but I think you would run into issues with the fact that html canvas can only render integer numbers of pixels. So in reality, you would only be able to move the square by a unit of one, twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just code a template of a simple game loop that you enhance late on, in this game loop I used `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead of `window.setInterval` so that we can stick to the native refresh loop of the browser, and you need to calculate by yourself the deltaTime so that you can run things smoothly.

This is the template that I came up with from your codebase:

```
<body>
  <canvas width="400" height="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    var a = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = a.getContext("2d");

    class player {
      constructor() {
        this.x = 200;
        this.y = 200;
        this.vel = 90;
        this.canMoveUp = false;
        this.canMoveDown = false;
        this.canMoveLeft = false;
        this.canMoveRight = false;
      }

      show() {
        c.clearRect(0, 0, a.width, a.height);
        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
      }

      moveUp(deltaTime) {
        this.y -= this.vel * deltaTime;
      }
      moveDown(deltaTime) {
        this.y += this.vel * deltaTime;
      }
      moveLeft(deltaTime) {
        this.x -= this.vel * deltaTime;
      }
      moveRight(deltaTime) {
        this.x += this.vel * deltaTime;
      }
      
      updatePos(deltaTime){
        if(this.canMoveUp) this.moveUp(deltaTime);
        if(this.canMoveDown) this.moveDown(deltaTime);
        if(this.canMoveLeft) this.moveLeft(deltaTime);
        if(this.canMoveRight) this.moveRight(deltaTime);
      }
    }

    var player1 = new player();

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.code === "ArrowDown") player1.canMoveDown = true;
      if (e.code === "ArrowUp") player1.canMoveUp = true;
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") player1.canMoveLeft = true;
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") player1.canMoveRight = true;
    }, false);
    
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.code === "ArrowDown") player1.canMoveDown = false;
      if (e.code === "ArrowUp") player1.canMoveUp = false;
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") player1.canMoveLeft = false;
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") player1.canMoveRight = false;
    }, false);

    var now, deltaTime, lastTime = window.performance.now();

    function frame() {
      now = window.performance.now();
      deltaTime = (now - lastTime) / 1000;
      player1.updatePos(deltaTime);
      player1.show(deltaTime);
        lastTime = now;
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding about setInterval , you can read it here https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Genertic syntax is :

```
let timerId = setInterval(func|code, [delay], [arg1], [arg2], ...)
```

Example :

```
setInterval(show, <specify the time in milliseconds> )
```